# Crash after plugging in the Logitech H600 wireless transmitter

Tags: 12.04, logitech, headset

I recently bought the Logitech H600 Wireless Headset. When I plug in the USB wireless transmitter, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS crashes.

How does that come and what do you suggest me to do?

---

Same problem here, as soon as the H600 headset is plugged in 12.04 crashes.

Relevant snip from /var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log is below, complete log can be found as a [gist](https://raw.github.com/gist/2909320/64051f9b4ca29788dec91ee49c687bc9f0152e09/gistfile1.txt)

```
[  2676.496] (**) Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset: Applying InputClass "evdev keyboard catchall"
[  2676.496] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset'
[  2676.496] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so
[  2676.496] (**) Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset: always reports core events
[  2676.496] (**) evdev: Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset: Device: "/dev/input/event16"
[  2676.496] (--) evdev: Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset: Vendor 0x46d Product 0xa29
[  2676.496] (--) evdev: Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset: Found absolute axes
[  2676.496] (--) evdev: Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset: Found absolute multitouch axes
[  2676.496] (--) evdev: Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset: Found keys
[  2676.496] (II) evdev: Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset: Configuring as mouse
[  2676.496] (II) evdev: Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset: Configuring as keyboard
[  2676.496] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.2/2-1.2.2:1.3/input/input16/event16"
[  2676.496] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset" (type: KEYBOARD, id 10)
[  2676.496] (**) Option "xkb_rules" "evdev"
[  2676.496] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[  2676.496] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[  2676.497] (II) evdev: Logitech Logitech Wireless Headset: initialized for absolute axes.
[  2676.497] 
Backtrace:
[  2676.497] 0: /usr/bin/X (xorg_backtrace+0x37) [0xb7698637]
[  2676.497] 1: /usr/bin/X (0xb7510000+0x18c3ba) [0xb769c3ba]
[  2676.497] 2: (vdso) (__kernel_rt_sigreturn+0x0) [0xb74ed40c]
[  2676.497] 3: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7155000+0x135d32) [0xb728ad32]
[  2676.497] 4: /usr/bin/X (XIChangeDeviceProperty+0x16c) [0xb7630b0c]
[  2676.497] 5: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/evdev_drv.so (0xb3f4a000+0x634e) [0xb3f5034e]
```

Comment: any log messages...

Comment: not that i can see, ill try to get a picture of the screen when it crashes

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in 12.04. There is no workaround or fix at the moment (aside from not plugging in the dongle).

The cause is a bug that was introduced in the update of X.org, which recognizes the device as having "buttons" but can't sort out where to send the input from them.

Answer (score -2):

Fix: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12060775#post12060775

This bug was fixed in the proposed updates.

Add these to the distro by selecting:
Ubuntu Software Centre -> Edit -> Software Sources -> Updates -> [X] (precise-proposed)

Then execute the following code:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo restart
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.