# Ubuntu 12.04 black screen while using Logitech headset wireless dongle

Tags: logitech

As soon as I attach my Logitech headset wireless dongle to my computer a black screen appears and doesn't go away.

Please help.

Comment: This seems a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/144290/crash-after-plugging-in-the-logitech-h600-wireless-transmitter

Comment: This unanswered question is about EOL Ubuntu 12.04 and OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years. VTC this abandoned question as `not reproducible`.